# Painting a Wall and Calculating the Paint Percentage in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm trying to paint a wall in Unity by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCD8Pt1zf4c&ab_channel=DitzelGames) however I don't know how can I calculate the paint percentage and not paint the lines that have been already painted, and also not go beyond plane boundaries. Painting needs to be using swerve mechanics.

What would be the approach to accomplish this?

Comment: This seems to be three separate questions. You may want to ask separate questions, and take some time to explain your terminology ("swerve", and "paint the lines that have already been painted" in this case).

Comment: "Swerve" => Painting with free movement, not one by one for example
"not paint the lines that have been already painted" => If I use raycast approach I Instantiate a brush prefab on that coordinate, it means it will double every time (but maybe this would be issue that I can fix if paint with solid color).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wn3j38SzSpk&t=241s&ab_channel=VeryHotShark

This video is quite near to what I'm looking for but I also need to draw freely (for example: diagonal line)

@WeckarE.

Comment: To help you we would need to go over the tutorial (which many dont have the time or access currently - always post code). If you need swerve mechanic and don't have them, post how you do it currently (with code). If you want to limit your painting to a plane, post the code how you paint on a plane. Your code should include everything that we need to be able to reproduce it locally (aka if you post it to a new scene, does it work there out of the box?)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Zibelas. You're right, maybe I need to change the question to this. What would be the simplest approach to paint the wall and finding the percentage of the painting? Any resource, technique, idea appreciated.

Comment: I think your tutorial covers it good enough for painting, quick google for percentage returns things like https://answers.unity.com/questions/1509375/how-can-i-check-how-many-pixels-on-a-texture-are-t.html you can modify the script to count for your color. Depends as well how big your paint area is, how often you need to calculate the percentage.

Comment: @Zibelas Which tutorial? Raycasting or shader?

Comment: Welcome. The tutorial mentions that at some point the result is saved as PNG. There are our clues. If the result is saved as PNG, you can reload as a Texture2D in Unity and do [pixel level access](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html). Probably expensive operation, but walk the resulting array is probably as fast as you can get. For example, you can sum all the pixels different than the initial color and divide by the total to get a float from 0.0f to 1.0f (for safety, cast operands to float). The answer linked in above comment has all you need for pixel access.